# How to solve the following subprocess error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, subprocess

I am not able to find anything on google regarding this. I am running this file for the first on a new system. It would be nice if someone could help on this issue. I installed a few libraries in the virtual env. Reset path variables but I get the same error.

My driver.py file which I am trying to execute. A snippet of code

```
import subprocess
import time
start = time.time()

output1 = subprocess.check_output("python fyp1dlib.py test_video.mp4", shell=True)
output2 = subprocess.check_output("fyp2.exe test_video.mp4", shell=True) #line 8 in error of driver.py

elapsed =  time.time() - start

output1=str(output1)[2:-5]
output2=str(output2)[2:-5]


# print(output1)
# print(output2)


print("Time to process ",elapsed)
```

The error I am facing

```
2021-06-19 21:58:07.369175: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2021-06-19 21:58:07.369920: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fyp2.py", line 259, in <module>
  File "fyp2.py", line 13, in get_landmark_model
  File "tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 189, in load_model
  File "tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 113, in parse_saved_model
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: pose_model/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
[25716] Failed to execute script fyp2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 8, in <module>
    output2 = subprocess.check_output("fyp2.exe test_video.mp4", shell=True)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'fyp2.exe test_video.mp4' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

What approach should I take to solve it? Any similar question already posted (if any) would also help.

Comment: I can edit the question and add more to above code if needed.

Comment: The subprocess is not an error, this is your actual error: OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: pose_model/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Comment: what is that file model exactly? @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: From our point of view, this is your code, we have no idea what model file your code uses.